# SharePoint is redirecting to different places (depending on the username) when clicking on the username text

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

I have a community site and clicking on the username text, will take to one of these two places, depending on the username, so the redirection will either be to:-

1. /_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=
2. About Me

But since some users have deleted their personal sites, so SharePoint will try to redirect to “About me ” page which is no longer exists. While for other users the redirection will be to the required URL which is  `/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=.`
So is there a way to force all the redirection to be to the `/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=`, instead of “About ME”?
can disabling the user profile managed service solve this issue? as inside my development environment i did not create a user profile servive, unlike the staging environment , and inside the dev server all redirection is being to the `/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off My Sites and they will all get directed to the basic UsersDisp page instead.

Comment: how to disabled it , you mean to disable the user profile managed service ?

Comment: i delete the User Profile server, and now all the redirection is being to the UserDisp page.

Comment: I am curious for both of you. Do you not need People Search, Personal Sites or Social Features like Newsfeeds?

Comment: no currently i do not need these.